# JQuery Animation On click trigger

Tags: jquery, animation, click, toggle

In the link stated down, I have a problem with triggering the rotation of the arrow upon clicking on the collapssing item and it does only work when i click on the arrow itself how can i change that ? 
Thank you,

Demo: jsfiddle.net/dw03z9t4/3/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your problem. Just traversing the DOM to get what you need.

```
$(".collapsed").click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggleClass("down");
});
```

However I should also mention that there is another unrelated problem. If you open a card and then open another, the arrow does not rotate back to its correct position in the first card. Figured I'd throw that in here.

Comment: Thank you that really helped me. However I found a new issue with my code: when i click to close a card the page automatically scrolls down until it gets the next card at the top of the page which is really frustrating and not so great to see do you have an idea how to avoid that ?